# Hall subgroup property

Tags: group-theory

I need help to prove a property regarding of Hall subgroups.

Let $N$ be a normal subgroup of $G$. If $T/N \in Hall_\pi(G/N)$ and $S \in Hall_\pi(T)$ then $S\in Hall_\pi(G)$

I have managed to show that for any Hall subgroup $H$ of $G$, $H\cap N$ is a hall subgroup of $N$ and $HN/N$ is a hall subgroup of $G/N$

Comment: There is no group theory involved here. Just write down the orders of everything as products of a $\pi$-number and a $\pi'$-number, and you will find that $S$ has order the largest $\pi$-factor of $|G|$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $|G/N:T/N|=|G:T|$ and $|G:S|=|G:T|\cdot |T:S|$.

Answer (score 0):

$[G : S] = [G : T][T : S]$
         = $[G/N : T/N][T : S]$

Now since $[G/N : T/N]$ is a $\pi'$-number and $[T : S]$ is a $\pi'$-number, we must have that $[G : S]$ is a $\pi'$-number. Also we know that $|S|$ is a  $\pi$-number.

Is this the correct reasoning for the answer?